# When do the Wolff-Kishner Reduction and Clemmensen Reduction not take place for carbonyl compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I came across some examples of organic compounds with acidic groups that didn't undergo the Clemmensen reduction. So, I was wondering which types of compounds the two reagents cannot reduce. Also, why?

Comment: Clemmensen relies on the carbonyl group protonating. If it is not the site of first protonation then it is not going to reduce.  Similar for W-K; if the hydrazone cannot be deprotonated because another site is more acidic then the reaction will not proceed.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/mozingo-reduction-mechanism

Comment: @Waylander Okay, so if there was a carboxylic group, then the reduction wouldn't take place, right?

Comment: Pretty much. Once the carboxyl group is deprotonated you are trying to form a dianion for W-K. For Clemmensen the carboxyl group may well be site of first protonation but it may be easier for the carbonyl to be the site